# Back button needs to redirect to last visited page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In web site I have to add "Back" button or Link URL which will redirects to me previously visited page.
Currently I have added below code, but it doesn't always work.

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.history.back();"><i>Back</i></a>
```

I observed that it is not working in Google chrome.

Comment: `onclick="window.history.go(-1);"`

Comment: _It doesn't always work_. When does it not work? When there is no history?

Comment: according to http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp `window.history.back()` should work in all major browsers if there is any history

Comment: w3school is full of bullshit as usual, even when you report a error on one of their pages they won't correct it.

Comment: A better reference would be: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function sample(){
window.location.href = window.history.back(1);
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="trying" onclick="sample()"/>
```

I have tested here it is working [test](http://jsfiddle.net/9HPgw/5/) ... :)

Event this work as same

```
 <a href="#" onclick="window.location.href = window.history.back(1);"><i>Back</i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
<input action="action" type="button" value="Back" onclick="history.go(-1);" />
```

Answer (score -1):

**The following was an incorrect assumption by me**

The value passed to `onclick` should be a function to call when the link is clicked. You are passing window.history.back() which is the value returned by the back function.

Try the following.

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.history.back;"><i>Back</i></a>
```

---

Turns out I assumed, incorrectly, that the value of onClick should be a function to call on click. As Brian North and putvande pointed out in the comments it should be the javascript code to run when the event is triggered.

**Suggestion**

However one should generally avoid binding events in the way you are doing as it couples presentation, HTML, too tightly with the javascript. Instead one should bind the click listener from an external javascript file using for example [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) or [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

### jQuery example

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="history-back">Back</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    $("#history-back").on("click", window.history.back);
});
```

Comment: You SHOULD pass the function (including `()`) otherwise it won't work at all.

Comment: The on[event] (onclick, onfocus, etc.) attributes accept function *body* - not function references.

Comment: No they don't both work, if I add your code and try it, the browser isn't going anywhere. Try and add `window.history.back;` to your console and hit return. Now try it with `window.history.back();`

Comment: @putvande No it doesn't work in the console of course, but passing it to `onclick` as `window.history.back` works under the latest Chrome on Mac for me.

Comment: @putvande That's weird, are you on the same OS and browser as me? E.g Chrome 31, OS X. 

Anyhow I have changed the answer to reflect what you've pointed out. I incorrectly assumed how `on[event]` works. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: Without `()` in `back`, I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`